# Trying to setup clang and llvm on Mac OSX to run runC with gedit

Tags: c, llvm, clang

Ive been having an issue trying to get clang to work in mac OSX 10.8, I am a student and currently learning C and the class wants me to set up a environment in gedit using a script called runC. everything is working however when I try to compile gedit says :

"need clang+llvm-3.1 to use runc.Try downloading this package from http://clang.llvm.org/ "

Ive tried to build it for mac but no luck yet, if Anyone knows how to do this please explain to me! I am familiar with terminal but not too great so sorry if some things might be confusing to me.

(also the school provides a ubuntu build with everything set up but Id rather not use that if possible since its through virtual box)

Comment: Why not just download Xcode from the Mac App store (free), then install the command line tools (which will include clang)

Comment: "no luck yet" - what errors are you getting? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

taking waterloo's cs136? I encountered this problem,too. I think it is because llvm just updated to 3.2 and the runC script haven't updated yet.

Comment: But you still can download 3.1 :)